# A Problem  about partitioning $S^2$

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Question: Can the 2-dimensional sphere $S^2$ be partitioned into four nonempty sets such that every circle in $S^2$  passes through just three  of these four sets?

Here, "just three" means "exactly three", circle is in the ordinary sense, i.e. round circle (or say 1-sphere), not necessarily great circle. If "just three" means "at most three" as Alexandre Eremenko supposed, then the answer is yes (there are a lot of examples). For example, see the example just given by Lee Mosher.

EDIT. I prove that if such partitioning exists, then these four subsets are all dense in $S^2$. So, it seems that we cannot find a "trivial" partition.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you mean circles in the literal sense, round circles.
I suppose "just three" means "at most three". The answer is "yes".

Let us identify your sphere with the extended
complex plane via stereographic projection, so that your
circles are straight lines or circles. Consider the following sets $A,B,C,D$.

Let $D=\{ \infty  \}$, $C=\{ 0 \}$, $A$ the set of points with argument
commensurable with $\pi$,
and $B$ the set of points with argument non-commensurable with $\pi$.
These sets partition the extended plane.
If a circle does not contain $D$, it intersects at most 3 sets.
If it contains $D$, it is a straight line. If this straight line
does not contain $C$, it intersects at most 3 sets.
If it contains $C$, it intersects either $C,A,D$ or $C,B,D$ but not all 4.

Sorry, do not know how to make curly braces {} with Mathjack.

Comment: For the non projected version, let C and D be (singleton sets of) antipodal points, and then partition the (pairs of) great circle arcs between them into two sets. Gerhard "Wish I Thought Of That" Paseman, 2012.12.28

Comment: You can do the curly braces by \lbrace and \rbrace in math mode. I learned this by right-clicking math in others' posts. You can literally see how they typed their math this way.

Comment: Further, if C had more than one point, I suspect there is no nontrivial two coloring of the remainder that would avoid a circle with four colors.  Gerhard "Not A Geometric Ramsey Theorist" Paseman, 2012.12.28

Comment: With Alexandre's example in mind, I think a painting argument shows that any such coloring must have two of the colors limited to singleton sets.  Looking at the circles passing through D and C, they determine a pencil of pairs of arcs which must be monochromatic off of the C and D regions, and then D and C' (C' also having color of C) determines a distinct pencil from the first (excepting one pair of arcs). It then becomes clear that any connected open subset not colored by C or D is monochromatic.  Gerhard "Some Details Remain, Of Course" Paseman, 2012.12.28

Comment: Time to eat my words.  Pick a sphere colored A, then pick a circle on it and color it B.  Then pick three points on the circle and color two of them C and one of them D. Any circle that has D, C, and B points must avoid the A color.  This example can be generalized, but I don't see any set but A having measure greater than zero (with respect to the measure of spherical area).  Gerhard "Please Pass The Salt Shaker" Paseman, 2012.12.28

Comment: And, of course, this last example is similar to Lee Mosher's example.  Time for me  to stop.  Gerhard "Dizzy From Coming Full Circle" Paseman, 2012.12.28

Comment: Actually, my last example allows for monochromatic circles, regardless of whether they are great or not. Lee's example specifically prohibits monochromatic great circles.  I suspect there is no coloring that has every circle with exactly three of the four colors, and certainly no such coloring must have a monchromatic open subset. Your example is not likely to be bested soon. Gerhard "Making More Words To Eat" Paseman, 2012.12.28

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko: There is a mistake in your construction. The line containing C and A  passes through both B and D.

Comment: @woodbass: I do not understand your objection: there is no 
"line containing A" in my example; A is a dense set in my example.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko:Does not "A the set of points with argument commensurable with $\pi$" imply that A is the ray $(-\infty,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}$? $B=\mathbb{C}-A-\lbrace{0\lbrace}$? My understanding is correct?

Answer (score 3):

First partition the equator into three nonempty sets such that every antipodal pair intersects exactly two of them. Then take the fourth set to be the complement of the equator.

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand my question. Under your partition, every circle in the the complement of the equator (i.e. the fourth set) passes through the fourth set only.

Comment: I took it to mean a great circle. If not, do you mean round circles? Topologically embedded circles? 

Comment: Why not partition some circle S into 3 arbitrary 
non-empty sets, and the
complement of S is the 4-th set. Let C be any round circle.
It intersects S at at most 2 points, or coincides with  S.
So it intersects at most 3 sets.

Comment: Indeed,as I observed also in a comment to your solution, Alexandre. Your solution has the feature that at least two colors occur on every  circle though, which is not the case for this last suggestion. Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.12.29

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko: There is a mistake in your construction. The line containing C and A passes through both B and D.

Comment: Woodbass, your comments are unclear to me.  One of my suggestions is an example with monochromatic circles. Eremenko's example is a stereographic projection, with a coloring that has two singleton point classes.  Any circle through the two points has (by construction) points of only one other color.  Any line through C does not intersect both A and B, while any circle through C avoids D.  I do not see any coloring yet in which all circles are tricolored.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Color Counting" Paseman, 2013.01.12

Comment: @ Gerhard Paseman:If "A the set of points with argument commensurable with $\pi$" implies that A is the ray $(-\infty,0)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, then my understanding is correct and so is my objection. 

Comment: @woodbass: the argument $\alpha$ is called commensurable with $\pi$
if $\alpha/\pi$ is rational. So the set $A$ consists of punctured lines (lines with $0$ deleted), not of rays.

Comment: @Alexandre Eremenko: I am sorry for misunderstanding your construction and take my objection back cordially.